# Why is Get-ChildItem not working

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to write a script to loop through child items using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet but it does not seem to be recognised.

```
$path = "master:/sitecore/content"
$x = Get-ChildItem $path
Write-Host $x.Name
```

Gives me the error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Method not found: 'Void System.Management.Automation.Provider.ContainerCmdletProvider.GetChildItems(System.String, Boolean, UInt32)'.
At line:2 char:6
+ $x = Get-ChildItem $path
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], MissingMethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMethodException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I am using Sitecore 8.2 rev 161115, SXA 1.2 rev 161216, SPE 4.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is related to the following [bug in SPE 4.4](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/827). There are 2 courses of action you can take:

1. Upgrade your Windows PowerShell to 5. (Windows Management Framework 5.x)
2. Upgrade SPE to 4.5

Actually taking the approach #2 is preferable as we've fixed quite a few other issues there and Upgrading Windows PowerShell can have consequences on your whole environment and is not always allowed by the systems administrators.